# If $1 = c . \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx$ , then what is c?

Tags: integration

I basically wonder if $\displaystyle \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx$ is convergent or divergent, and if convergent, what is it equal to?

Comment: $c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$ This is a classical result

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at what the integral provides in a slightly more general case:
\begin{align}
\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{- a x^2} \, dx &= 2 \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- a x^2} \, dx \\
&=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \, \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- t} \, t^{- \frac{1}{2}} \, dt  \hspace{5mm} \text{where} \,  t = a \, x^2\\
&= \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}
\end{align}
Now if it is required that
$$1 = c \, \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} e^{- a \, x^2} \, dx$$
then it is determined that
$$c = \sqrt{\frac{a}{\pi}}$$.

Answer (score 0):

The pdf of normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}e^{-x^2}$.

Since, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx = 1 \implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx = 1$